# Averaging elements in array of arrays by index using functional programming

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

I have an array of arrays of Doubles. For example:

```
let mceGain = [[3,4,5],[7,4,3],[12,10,7]] // Written as integers for simplicity here
```

I would now like to average the elements in the different arrays with corresponding indexes. So I would have an output looking somewhat like this:

```
//firstAvg: (3+7+12)/3 = 7.33
//secondAvg: (4+4+10)/3 = 6
//thirdAvg: (5+3+7)/3 = 5
```

Then finally I would like to store these averages in a simpler array:

```
//mceGain: [7.33,6,5]
```

I have tried to do this with a double for-loop with a switch-statement inside, but this seems to be unnecessarily complicated. I assume the same result could be achieved using a combination of `reduce()`, `map()` and `filter()`, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I would do as a composition of two separate, simpler operations: first transpose `[[3, 4, 5], [7, 4, 3], [12, 10, 7]]`, to produce `[[3, 7, 12],  [4, 4, 10], [5, 3, 7]]`, then average each subarray with `map` to produce `[7.33, 6, 5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your comment below

```
let elms: [[Double]] = [[3, 5, 3], [4, 4, 10] , [5, 3, 7]]

func averageByIndex(elms:[[Double]]) -> [Double]? {
    guard let length = elms.first?.count else { return []}

    // check all the elements have the same length, otherwise returns nil
    guard !elms.contains(where:{ $0.count != length }) else { return nil }

    return (0..<length).map { index in
        let sum = elms.map { $0[index] }.reduce(0, +)
        return sum / Double(elms.count)
    }
}

if let averages = averageByIndex(elms: elms) {
    print(averages) // [4.0, 4.0, 6.666666666666667]
}
```

Comment: This gives me the average of each subarray. What I am looking for is the average of the sum of the ith element of each subarray. :=)

Comment: Thank you. Very nicely structured.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyse what you want to do here. You start with an array of arrays:

```
[[3,4,5],[7,4,3],[12,10,7]]
```

and you want to transform each subarray into a number:

```
[7,6,5]
```

Whenever you have this kind of "transform each element of this sequence into something else" situation, use `map`.

When you compute the average, you need to transform a sequence of things into just one thing. This means that we need `reduce`.

```
let array: [[Double]] = [[3,4,5],[7,4,3],[12,10,7]]
let result = array.map { $0.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 }) / Double($0.count) }
```

With comments:

```
let array: [[Double]] = [[3,4,5],[7,4,3],[12,10,7]]
let result = array.map { // transform each element like this:
    $0.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 }) // sums everything in the sub array up 
    / Double($0.count) } // divide by count
```

EDIT:

What you need to do is to "transpose" the array first, then do the map and reduce:

```
array[0].indices.map{ index in // these three lines makes the array [[3, 7, 12], [4, 4, 10], [5, 3, 7]]
    array.map{ $0[index] }
}
.map { $0.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 }) / Double($0.count) }
```

Comment: This gives me the average of each subarray. What I am looking for is the average of the sum of the `ith` element of each subarray. Very nice analysis though!

Comment: @matiastofteby Edited.

Comment: I wish I could give best answer to you both. :=)